# Inject @Named , @Stateful to @Singleton EJB

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, entitymanager

Is there any way to inject @Named bean to Singleton?

Here's the class that needs to be injected

```
@Named
@Stateful
@ConversationScoped
public class PlaySessionBean implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test-persistence-unit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
....
}
```

The bean is used for view utility (generated by Forge)

The problem is that I need to access the `PlaySessionBean` from @Startup @Singleton

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StartupBean.class.getName());

  private EntityManager entityManager;
  private static EntityManagerFactory factory =
      Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("wish-to-paris-persistence-unit");
  private List<PlaySession> playSessions;

  @PostConstruct
  public void run() {
    this.entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaQuery<PlaySession> criteria =
        this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(PlaySession.class);
    this.playSessions =
        this.entityManager.createQuery(criteria.select(criteria.from(PlaySession.class)))
            .getResultList();
    this.entityManager.close();
  }
 ....
```

But it always failed and complained that PlaySession is not an Entity

Is there a way to inject the Named Stateful bean to Singleton?
If not, is there any workaround for it?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `PlaySession` an entity indeed? Is it annotated with `@Entity` and is it mapped to a corresponding repository table using the `@Table` annotation?

Comment: What approach did you take and what worked?

Comment: hello @BuhakeSindi, as per your answer below, it worked and the stateful bean were injected to the `singleton` as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing CDI scoping with EJB states. I would rather that you choose either CDI or EJB but not mix the 2. For one, transaction management is different between the 2 architectures. Also, the life cycle of each objects are completely different.

If you are going to use EJB and call the respective session bean, you can annotate your `@Stateful` Session Bean as a `@LocalBean` since your session bean as no interface inheritance.

Example:

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class PlaySessionBean implements Serializable {

}
```

Then on your `@Startup` Singleton bean, you can simply reference it by:

```
@EJB
private PlaySessionBean playSessionBean;
```

The EJB Session Bean will still be stateful.

Comment: Because the `PlaySessionBean` in my project is used as CRUD for view by Forge, I have to create another class which injects `EntityManager` and with the mentioned `@Stateful` and `@LocalBean` on it and injects it to the `@Startup @Singleton` bean.

Thanks. this solution works